# Pass data backward from detailViewController to masterViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to pass data back from the second viewController.
I can do that without NavigationController. But now I need to use NavigationController. Then my code does work as before. The data wont pass.
Here is the simple code:
In first viewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, backfromSecond {

    @IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!

    var string : String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.string = "Start here"
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.text.text = self.string
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? secondViewController{
            destinationViewController.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func back(text: String) {
        self.string = text
        print(text)
    }
}
```

And Second viewController:

```
    protocol backfromSecond {
    func back(text: String)
    } 
    class secondViewController: UIViewController {
    var string : String = "nothing here"
    var delegate : backfromSecond?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate?.back(text: string)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Where is UINavigationController ??

Comment: Is UINavigationController embedded to SecondViewController ???

Comment: These two Controllers are embedded to UINavigationController

Comment: The `delegate` property should definitely be `weak`, but that won't stop the data from passing back. Apart from that, the code you have posted works (I tried it). Something must be wrong elsewhere.

Comment: @ganzogo You click back button and the label changed?

Comment: I did that in viewWillAppear, as you can see.

Comment: Ah yes, the label does change (missed the `viewWillAppear` method).

Comment: Why mine does not...I am so sad.

Comment: Do you get `nothing here` printed to the console?

Comment: No, seems like the data have been passed back

Comment: I don't understand. Do you get `nothing here` printed to the console when you load the second view controller?

Comment: Yes, I have `nothing here` in the second view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose A & B are two controllers and you first navigated from A to B with some data. And now you want to POP from B to A with some data.

Unwind Segues is the best and recommended way to do this.
Here are the steps.

1. Open A.m
2. define following method

   @IBAction func unwindSegueFromBtoA(segue: UIStoryNoardSegue) {

   }
3. open storyboard
4. Select B ViewController and click on ViewController outlet. press control key and drag to 'Exit' outlet and leave mouse here. In below image, selected icon is ViewController outlet and the last one with Exit sign is Exit Outlet.
   [image]
5. You will see 'unwindSegueFromBtoA' method in a popup . Select this method .
6. Now you will see a segue in your view controler hierarchy in left side. You will see your created segue near StoryBoard Entry Piont in following Image.

[image: You View Hierarchy]

7. Select this and set an identifier to it. (suggest to set the same name as method - unwindSegueFromBtoA)
8. Open B.m . Now, wherever you want to pop to A. use

   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindSegueFromBtoA", sender: dataToSend)
9. Now when you will pop to 'A', 'unwindSegueFromBtoA' method will be called. In unwindSegueFromBtoA of 'A' you can access any object of 'B'.
10. That's it..!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the prepare for segue method. If the view controller is on a navigation stack i think your code should be something like

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController).topViewController as! secondViewController{
        destinationViewController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works me well.

1st VC

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, backfromSecond {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
  @IBAction func Passingfrom1stVCTo2ndVC(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController3") as? ViewController3{
            vc.dataFrom1StVC = "message send from 1st VC"
            vc.delegate = self
           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func back(text: String) {
        print("data\(text)")
    }
    }
```

2nd VC.

```
protocol backfromSecond: class {
    func back(text: String)
}

class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    var dataFrom1StVC : String? = nil
    week var delegate : backfromSecond?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func DataSendFrom2ndVCTo1stVC(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.delegate?.back(text: "Message Send From 2nd vc to 1st VC")
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

I hope it will work you. If any problem then ask me i will help you.

Comment: You also have a memory leak. The delegate property should be weak.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unwind segues to pass data back.
Here's a tutorial
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/